# Get Window handle in Windows store app

Tags: camera, windows-store-apps, handle

I am working on a app which needs to have a custom camera capture dialog to enable zoom, flash etc. which default CameraCaptureUI does not  have. My app will be deployed on tablets and I have a .NET SDK (provided by tablet vendor) which I can use to enable zoom, flash and every other thing. The SDK is not compatible with windows store app and it uses Win32 api but I can still use some of it functions.
So this SDK have a preview method which requires window handle (InPtr) to start a preview. The problem is I cant find window handle for a store app window or rather I don't know how to find it. If i can find it somehow I am sure I will be able to implement other features easily enough.
Can someone show me how to find window handle in Windows store app?

Thanks a lot for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: http://tinyurl.com/pf5kpyv you *can* find the window handle of a store app using the Win32 API. But if your target is WinRT, you won't have the Win32 API available (probably you already know this). If your target is full Windows 8.1, it might be easier to just write it as a non-store app. Of course, if your client requires it to be "modern" than you're stuck :)

Comment: I am still lost on where and how to use this code. Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done what you are trying to do either so I have no special insight. I just went looking for something I thought might help. If I have time I'll look the code over, but your ability to examine it is probably just as good as mine :)